# Receive the number of top and the input row together

Tags: r, quanteda

I use this lines of code to receive in a final dataframe the number of topics and the input columns of a dataframe
All of them into one dataframe

```
library(quanteda)
library(stm)
df1 <- data.frame(freetext = c("open until monday night", "one more time to insert your coin"), numid = c(291,312))
myDfm <- df1$freetext %>%
     tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
     tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"), mystopwords)) %>%
     tokens_tolower()  %>%
     dfm()
my_lda_fit2 <- stm(myDfm, K = 2, verbose = FALSE)
quant_stm <- convert(myDfm, to = "stm")
result2 <- data.frame(quant_stm$meta,
                       maxtopic = apply(my_lda_fit2$theta,1,which.max))
```

Here is the result stems from the previous code:

```
maxtopic
2
1
```

Here is what I will expect to receive

```
freetext numid maxtopic
open until monday night 291 2
one more time to insert your coin 312 1
```

Any idea what different configuration should I make?

Comment: Does `cbind(df1,result2)` produce what you want?

Comment: @Duck I guess it could be but I am afraid if it could make wrong match

Comment: `cbind()` is not like `merge()`. It keeps data in same order. You should test on your data.